# How to access local XML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a html file, where I keep some notes and other info, I frequently update it, so it got quite big. The problem with that was, that if I change something in the layout, it gets really cumbersome, because I have to change it in so many places. So I had the idea, to put all the data into a XML and transform it into HTML with XSLT.

This immediately brought me to the first issue: I'm not able to access the XML.

The first thing I tried was loading it through XMLHttpRequest:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

But this gets blocked with "Reason: CORS request not HTTP". I know why I get it and I also know that there most likely is no way around that when using XMLHttpRequest. (except tampering with local browser security, which I don't want to do).

My next idea was to put the XML as string directly into the script and just parse it into a XML doc. Something like:

```
var rawXml = "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar/>
    <bar/>
</foo>
";
```

But this gets me a "Uncaught SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line". So apparently javascript doesn't support any form of verbatim strings and I have to escape all the linebreaks with a \n. My problem with that is, that I'm going to loose the pretty formatting. So reading and editing the XML is going to be a pain. That's definitely something I want to avoid.

EDIT:
Thanks to @Taplar for pointing out, that I can use a template literal, which makes the latter approach work.
This solution is not optimal, since I use NotePad++ and I can either use syntax highlighting for HTML or XML, plus XML Tools syntax autocheck gets screwed over by all the HTML code. But so far it is the best solution I have. Should there be any other options left, I'd like to hear them!

(As other people already pointed out to use `input type=file`, this is no real viable solution for me. I want to open the HTML document and read it. But with the input elements I have to first pick the XML and the pick the XSL. That's kinda cumbersome over which I prefer the xml-as-string solution)

Comment: you have to use the `input type=file` to select the file. you can't read a file by name in the browser.

Comment: FYI: Unless you are dealing with ancient browsers, do not use window.ActiveXObject

Comment: `""` strings do not allow literal new lines, unless they are escaped.  Also your nesting has `"` that would cause the string to terminate prematurely, even if you didn't have new line characters.  You should consider swapping to a template literal (`\`\``) that **do** allow for both.

Comment: @DanielA.White
That would mean, I have to open the html document and the click the button & pick a file. That's kinda cumbersome.

Comment: @Nikolaus it’s done that way for security reasons

Comment: @Taplar Awesome! That did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah, I know. But I don't want to trade for usability. Having the xml as string in the script is not perfect, but still the best solution so far. So I'm going with that until I find something better.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `XMLHttpRequestInstance.responseType` to `'document'`:

```js
function loadXMLDoc(filename, func){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  x.open('GET', filename); x.responseType = 'document';
  x.onload = d=>{
    func(d);
  }
  x.send();
  return x;
}
// here's how you would execute
loadXMLDoc('yourFile.xml', d=>{
  const productNodeList = d.getElementsByTagName('product');
});
```

Comment: That nets me the same error:
`"Reason: CORS request not HTTP"`

Comment: If your testing from `localhost` your issue is most likely that you have your Server serving via FTP, instead of HTTP. Fix your host settings.

Comment: There is no server involved. I'm just displaying a file, which lies in my file system.
The address bar in the browser looks like that:
`file:///C:/sample.html`

Comment: There's your issue. You are using the `file` protocol not `http`. You would use [requestFileSystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem) without a Server, but that is non-standard and only allows sandboxed access. You should have a Server. How will you serve your web pages? I would just use a Server and go `http`.

Comment: I'm not serving any web pages nor am I planning to.It is just a single HTML file (first sentence of the original post), which is lying in my OneDrive.

Comment: That makes no sense. All web pages are served, even if it's from localhost.